# Laravel friendship get user information

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm using the [friendship package by hootlex](https://github.com/hootlex/laravel-friendships) but I'm not quite sure how I get the user information (username etc.) when I'm getting all friend requests and displaying them in a foreach loop.

Basically what I have done is this, to return the view:

```
/**
 * @return mixed
 *
 * View friend requests
 */
public function getFriendRequests() {

    $user = Auth::user();

    return view('friends.requests')
        -> with([
            'profile' => $user -> profile,
            'user' => $user,
            'received_requests' => $user -> getFriendRequests(),
            'sent_requests' => $user -> getPendingFriendships()
        ]);

}
```

And then in my view:

```
<div class="block block-green">

<div class="block-head">
    <h4><i class="fa fa-fw fa-exclamation-circle"></i>Venneforespørsler ({{ count($received_requests) }})</h4>
</div>

<div class="block-body">

    @foreach ($received_requests as $rr)

        <div class="request">

            <div class="thumb">{{-- PROFILE THUMB HERE --}}</div>
            <div class="username">{{-- SENDERS USERNAME HERE --}}</div>
            <div class="actions">
                <form method="post" action="/friends/request/accept/{{ $rr -> id }}">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-check"></i>Aksepter</button>
                </form>
                <form method="post" action="/friends/request/deny/{{ $rr -> id }}">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-times"></i>Avslå</button>
                </form>
            </div>

        </div>

    @endforeach

</div>

</div>
```

So basically what I'm wondering, how would I get the username / other information from the `User` model on each friend request?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello can you please tell is this package ' friendship package by hootlex' is good for friendship structure like instagram? Is it bug free?

Comment: Yea i think its pretty good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **$rr** variable contains an object of class **Hootlex\Friendships\Models\Friendship** - you can see its source code here: https://github.com/hootlex/laravel-friendships/blob/master/src/Models/Friendship.php.

As you can see, this model allows you to access both **sender** and **recipient** of given friend request via properties of the same name.

Therefore, in order to get **username of the sender**, you'll need to access it with:

```
$rr->sender->username
```

Comment: Ahh, I see! So if I want to access the `Profile` related model to grab the profile picture, I could do: `$rr -> sender -> profile() -> picture`?