# Hootlex Friendship Laravel Get user information, from another model than User

Tags: php, laravel, social-network-friendship

I'm currently using Hootlex Laravel-Friendship for a website, but something seems not to work with me, let me explain:

I've got a model (LF_Profile), which is using Friendship vendor, everything work, except on this, I can't get the user information, I looked at this post ([Laravel friendship get user information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38846353/laravel-friendship-get-user-information)), I followed it, and it returns

> Property [sender] does not exist on this collection instance.

I'm trying to get the user information, but not working, maybe because I'm not using User model as everybody does?

Here is one code, to get ALl friendships

```
/**
 * Get all friendships
 *
 * @param  int $id
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function getAllFriendships($id){

  $lFProfile = $this->lFProfileRepository->findWithoutFail($id);

  if (empty($lFProfile)) {
    return $this->sendError('LfProfile not found');
  }

  $friendships=$lFProfile->getAllFriendships();
  return $this->sendResponse($friendships->toArray(), 'Get all friends');

}
```

Where getAllFrendships (comes from the vendor), is this:

```
public function getPendingFriendships($groupSlug = '')
{
    return $this->findFriendships(Status::PENDING, $groupSlug)->get();
}
```

It returns an array as this:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "id": 2,
        "sender_id": 1,
        "sender_type": "App\\Models\\LF_Profile",
        "recipient_id": 2,
        "recipient_type": "App\\Models\\LF_Profile",
        "status": 0,
        "created_at": "2017-08-24 10:45:30",
        "updated_at": "2017-08-24 10:45:30"
    }
]
}
```

In fact, it should return in the array the sender / recipient information.
If you want more details, just ask. As always thanks for helping me.

Comment: Please provide more details, like the part of code which is generating this error.

Comment: This error is returned when i do $lFProfile->getAllFriendShips->sender;
Whereas it should be a sender. But not for me :x

Comment: You need to be more specific and provide more details. We can't go through the entire tutorial until we reach this error. You need to tell us what you tried and show us exactly where you encountered this error, this will raise the chance of getting a good answer.

Comment: Ok sorry for this:
I edited my post, and gave more details